# Why do Major and Minor grooves exist in dna strands?

Tags: genetics, dna

I've been trying to find what causes the periodic appearance of major and minor grooves in DNA but have not yet been successful. Geometrical explanations would also be appreciated as I cannot understand any of the geometrical explanations I have come across so far. As far as my knowledge of DNA is concerned I know of all the high school basics (e.g complimentarity, bonding between the individual components of a nucleotide etc.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you have learned so far, and where exactly you're stuck. As it stands now, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

It is all explained [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_double_helix#Helix_geometries) in Wikipedia. You are referring to Watson-Crick base pairs in the B-DNA structure.